# Why do programmers say: "Did you meet the Spartans?"

Tags: meaning, expressions, idioms, pop-culture

English is not my maternal language and on development/IT forums, I've found the expressions "Did you meet the spartans?" or "I've met the spartans?". To set the context, they are speaking about a new computer language or technology and the difficulties they've faced.

I've done some research. Apparently, it refers to a movie which seems to be a torture to watch. Can anyone confirm or explain?

Comment: The 2006 film,  [**300**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0416449/), was a very gory movie, if I recall correctly. I didn't watch it to the end though, I don't remember  why. Tediousness? Nausea?  Overkill? Maybe it's become a cult movie among nerds, geeks, programmers? Or a type of shibboleth?

Comment: I think that they maybe refer to this one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet_the_Spartans

Comment: Were you just looking for the history of Spartans ...the web is full of it!!!!

Comment: @BenjaminBALET - Yeah, that movie sounds like a lot more fun than 300.

Comment: @Josh61 the OP isn't asking for the history of Sparta, Meet the Spartans is probably a catchphrase among geeks etc. think of the movies: [*Meet the Fockers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet_the_Fockers) and its sequal *Meet the Parents.*

Comment: English is my native language, and I'm a programmer, and I've never heard that. I doubt anyone would give you flack for simply asking them what they meant.

Answer (score 1):

Just based on this sparse description, I consider it roughly equivalent with:

*That's nothing. Go fight/meet the Spartans and then talk!*

The Spartans demonstrated **legendary toughness**. They were a warrior's warriors.

> Whatever the reason Sparta's own contribution was just **300** Spartiates
>   (accompanied by their attendants and probably perioikoi auxiliaries),
>   the total force assembled for the defense of the pass of Thermopylae
>   came to something between four and seven thousand Greeks. They faced a
>   Persian army who had invaded from the north of Greece under Xerxes I.
>   Herodotus stated that this army consisted of over two million men;
>   modern scholars consider this to be an exaggeration and give estimates
>   ranging from **70,000 to 300,000**.[13]
>
> Xerxes waited four days to attack, hoping the Greeks would disperse.
>   Finally, on the fifth day the Persians attacked. Leonidas and the
>   Greeks repulsed the Persians' frontal attacks for the fifth and sixth
>   days, killing roughly 20,000 of the enemy troops. The Persian elite
>   Special Forces unit known to the Greeks as "the Immortals" was held
>   back, and two of Xerxes' brothers (Abrocomes and Hyperanthes) died in
>   battle.[14] On the seventh day (August 11), a Malian Greek traitor
>   named Ephialtes led the Persian general Hydarnes by a mountain track
>   to the rear of the Greeks.[15] At that point Leonidas sent away all
>   Greek troops and remained in the pass with his 300 Spartans, 900
>   Helots, and 700 Thespians who refused to leave. The Thespians stayed
>   entirely of their own will, declaring that they would not abandon
>   Leonidas and his followers. Their leader was Demophilus, son of
>   Diadromes, and as Herodotus writes: "Hence they lived with the
>   Spartans and died with them."
>
> One theory provided by Herodotus is that Leonidas sent away the
>   remainder of his men because he cared about their safety. The King
>   would have thought it wise to preserve those Greek troops for future
>   battles against the Persians, but he knew that the Spartans could
>   never abandon their post on the battlefield. The soldiers who stayed
>   behind were to protect their escape against the Persian cavalry.
>   Herodotus himself believed that Leonidas gave the order because he
>   perceived the allies to be out of heart and unwilling to encounter the
>   danger to which his own mind was made up. He therefore chose to
>   dismiss all troops except the Thespians and Helots and save the glory
>   for the Spartans.[11]
>
> Of the small Greek force, attacked from both sides, all were killed
>   except for the Thebans, who surrendered. Leonidas was killed, but the
>   Spartans retrieved his body and protected it. Herodotus says that
>   Xerxes' orders were to have Leonidas' head cut off and put on a stake
>   and his body crucified. This was considered sacrilegious.
>
> **Wikipedia**

You'll find better writing in

[Running With Pheidippides: Stylianos Kyriakides : The Miracle Marathoner](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Z-8bgF4qoLUC&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false)
 By Nick Tsiotos, Andy Dabilis

Comment: That's make sense. An example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755940/how-to-setup-hmvc-in-codeigniter-3-dev